# Visual Studio does not install correctly on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, visual-studio-cordova

I upgraded my laptop to Windows 10 (no preview edition - the real thing!).  I then installed Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 (I already have VS 2013 installed) so I can begin to use the Cordova functionality.  The install churns and burns for a long time and finally finishes with a pageful of warnings.  The warnings seem to correspond to entries in the log file (at the bottom of this post).
I have tried uninstalling / reinstalling VS2015 thinking that a connection issue was the culprit - this did not work.
I downloaded the ISO, uninstalled, and then reinstalled from the ISO - same problem.
Well, I thought that I would try to just create an app anyway, but I was greeted with the wonderful "Object not set to a reference...." message box which of course does not give you a clue as to what is going on.
So - I restarted VS2015 and just tried to create a new non-Cordova project - I was greeted with the same "Object not set to a reference..." dialog box.
I was able to open an existing VS 2013 project - it worked fine.
So, I tried to repeat this wonderful adventure on Windows 7.  Everything worked fine.
My conclusion is that there is some kind of issue between Win10 and VS2015.  VS2013 works great on both Win10 and Win7 - and VS2015 works fine on Win7.
I really want to upgrade our team to Win10 (some of them, sadly, are on Win8.1), and we also want to move to VS2015, but we cant go forward until we know what is going on here.

I finally installed the Cordova extensions CTP on VS 2013 (but I had to do this to both my Win10 and my Win7 box so I could share the Solution between them) just so I could get going - that works great.

I double checked and the BITS service says that it is running in the Win10 box.

Any help?

Log Snip below:

```
[2AB8:23DC][2015-08-04T07:41:17]i000: MUX:  Source confirmed
[2AB8:2954][2015-08-04T07:41:18]i000: MUX:  Finished connecting secondary installer pipe
[2AB8:23A4][2015-08-04T07:41:24]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: TypeScript for Visual Studio
[2AB8:23A4][2015-08-04T07:41:35]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: KB3073097
[2AB8:23A4][2015-08-04T07:44:21]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Windows 10 SDK 10.0.10240
[2AB8:23A4][2015-08-04T07:44:25]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Android SDK Setup (API Level 19 and 21)
[2AB8:23A4][2015-08-04T07:45:57]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android
[2AB8:23A4][2015-08-04T07:46:50]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Apache Ant (1.9.3)
[2AB8:23A4][2015-08-04T07:47:04]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Android Native Development Kit (R10E, 32 bits)
[2AB8:23A4][2015-08-04T07:52:55]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Tools for Windows 10 Universal Apps (Windows SDK 10.0.10240)
[2AB8:23A4][2015-08-04T07:53:00]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Android SDK Setup (API Level 22)
[2AB8:23A4][2015-08-04T07:53:02]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Visual C++ iOS Development
[2AB8:23A4][2015-08-04T07:53:08]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Visual C++ Android Development
[2AB8:23A4][2015-08-04T07:53:14]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: HTML/JavaScript (Apache Cordova) Update 1
[2AB8:23A4][2015-08-04T07:53:22]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: C#/.NET (Xamarin)
[2AB8:23A4][2015-08-04T07:58:05]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Emulators for Windows Mobile 10.0.10240
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:08]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (VSSecondaryInstaller_box) failed: Error Message Id: 1603 ErrorMessage: TypeScript for Visual Studio : This product did not download successfully: 
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:08]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (VSSecondaryInstaller_box) failed: Error Message Id: 1603 ErrorMessage: KB3073097 : This product did not download successfully: 
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:08]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (VSSecondaryInstaller_box) failed: Error Message Id: 1603 ErrorMessage: Windows 10 SDK 10.0.10240 : This product did not download successfully: 
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:08]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (VSSecondaryInstaller_box) failed: Error Message Id: 1603 ErrorMessage: Android SDK Setup (API Level 19 and 21) : This product did not download successfully: BITS download failed. BITS service may have been disabled on the machine.
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:08]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (VSSecondaryInstaller_box) failed: Error Message Id: 1603 ErrorMessage: Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android : This product did not download successfully: 
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:08]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (VSSecondaryInstaller_box) failed: Error Message Id: 1603 ErrorMessage: Apache Ant (1.9.3) : This product did not download successfully: 
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:08]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (VSSecondaryInstaller_box) failed: Error Message Id: 1603 ErrorMessage: Android Native Development Kit (R10E, 32 bits) : This product did not download successfully: 
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:08]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (VSSecondaryInstaller_box) failed: Error Message Id: 1603 ErrorMessage: Tools for Windows 10 Universal Apps (Windows SDK 10.0.10240) : This product did not download successfully: 
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:08]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (VSSecondaryInstaller_box) failed: Error Message Id: 1603 ErrorMessage: Android SDK Setup (API Level 22) : This product did not download successfully: 
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:08]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (VSSecondaryInstaller_box) failed: Error Message Id: 1603 ErrorMessage: Visual C++ iOS Development : This product did not download successfully: 
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:08]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (VSSecondaryInstaller_box) failed: Error Message Id: 1603 ErrorMessage: Visual C++ Android Development : This product did not download successfully: 
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:08]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (VSSecondaryInstaller_box) failed: Error Message Id: 1603 ErrorMessage: HTML/JavaScript (Apache Cordova) Update 1 : This product did not download successfully: 
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:08]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (VSSecondaryInstaller_box) failed: Error Message Id: 1603 ErrorMessage: C#/.NET (Xamarin) : This product did not download successfully: 
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:08]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (VSSecondaryInstaller_box) failed: Error Message Id: 1603 ErrorMessage: Emulators for Windows Mobile 10.0.10240 : This product did not download successfully: 
[1C70:27A4][2015-08-04T07:58:39]e000: Error 0x80048648: Process returned error: 0x80048648
[1C70:27A4][2015-08-04T07:58:39]e000: Error 0x80048648: Failed to execute EXE package.
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:39]e000: Error 0x80048648: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:39]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: VSSecondaryInstaller_box MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 4192628136  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 4186217896
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:39]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageComplete for secondary installer
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:39]i000: MUX:  Disconnecting secondary installer pipe
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:39]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x80048648 Msi Messages:TypeScript for Visual Studio : This product did not download successfully:  Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:39]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147187128 (0x80048648), Error Message=TypeScript for Visual Studio : This product did not download successfully: , Result Detail=, Vital=False, Package Action=Install, Package Id=VSSecondaryInstaller_box
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:39]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '0'
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:39]w350: Applied non-vital package: VSSecondaryInstaller_box, encountered error: 0x80048648. Continuing...
[2AB8:1968][2015-08-04T07:58:39]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: community_finalizer
```

Comment: `This product did not download successfully` seems clear enough...

Comment: however, there is no indication as to "where" it downloads from which is why I downloaded the ISO and tried installing from it with the same result.  To compound the issue, we installed update 5 on VS2013 which now breaks the Cordova preview.  And MS removed the update 4 so we cannot go back to that.  We are basically DOA.  Thanks Redmond!

Comment: Try to clean 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache... and reinstall from ISO. Also check iso hash for any defects...

Comment: I uninstalled, deleted everything in the package cache, and tried again from the ISO.  it ended stating it was successful, and asked for a RESTART.  I did the restart, and a that caused several reboots with the message on the screen stating windows was updating, do not turn off.  it finally finished and then a VS2015 install started.  when that finished it got the same messages of the same components that could not download. I tried opening a project anyway, it said the cordova tools were not installed and tried to install them with the same results.  MS, please fix your install on Win10.

Comment: I have similar problems and tried the solutions. Nothing worked.
Look forward to another solution

Comment: After multiple attempts, and trying the helpful suggestions here, I finally ended up formatting my hard drive and deciding to wait on VS 2015 until some service packs come out.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered similar problem in installing VS2013 update 5(iso version).

If you somehow messed up the installation/re-installation/Update of VS2013 in Windows 10, here are the steps I followed for successful operation:

1. Turn off system restore (temporarily).
2. Turn off AVG antivirus - until next reboot and turn off identity AVG
   protection in task manager. Do the same thing if you're using another
   antivirus.
3. Install/Uninstall/Update Visual Studio 2013.
   When install/reinstall/update stalls, end the 64 bit windows installer
   in task manager and the operation will proceed. Do the same thing
   if the same happens until the operation is finished successfully.
4. Make sure windows installer is not running in task manager for next
   steps.
5. Run subincl.exe (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/astebner/solving-setup-errors-by-using-the-subinacl-tool-to-repair-file-and-registry-permissions).
6. Run command in admin mode and go to `\ProgramData\Package Cache`
   and run the command: `Del /F /S *.msiDelete /F /S *.cab.`
7. Install/Reinstall/Update.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. I can't tell you how much I loathe Microsoft after 5 fantastic years with only linux and OSX....

Comment: For 2013 update 5, we found the solution was to remove the *.suo file(s) in the solution's base directory and restart Visual Studio.  Simple!

Answer (score 5):

I found many problems with VS2015 on Windows 10. Too many to mention.

One method that might work is to reinstall all 3rd party tools after installing VS2015. For example, install VS2015 and components. Next uninstall anything related to Cordova on your OS. Next install 3rd party Cordova components one-by-one, and finally reinstall & repair VS2015 Cordova components. I have not yet tried using Cordova on VS2015 & Windows 10.

However, for example, upgrading to Windows 10 after installing VS2015 will completely corrupt your Hyper-V environment. This can be fixed by hacking around your Hyper-V settings. However this also blows away your Genymotion & VirtualBox installation (which must be reinstalled). Also the Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android does *not* work at all - do not waste your time. I have mine uninstalled.

These issues are known at Microsoft (I've had direct emails with key MS employees on these topics in the last 48 hours) and they say they are working on it.

Definitely a work in progress. Good luck using VS2015 on Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for the response - at least it is good to know we are not alone!  I will try the one-at-a-time approach you suggested, and in the next day or so post my results.

Answer (score 2):

I got same problem because of network issue when I install package.
because of the download cache, the problem can't be fix when I prepare install VS2015.

at last, I remove all folders under "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache" then reinstall VS2015, don't worry , it's very quickly.

the problem be solved.

good luck!!!

Comment: I tried that as well (see earlier comments) with no success.  Glad it worked for you.

Comment: hey @huangchaosuper - I used this solution 'cos it failed to install TypeScript properly. This solution worked to fix that issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing in a VM then there is no solution, the emulators are virtual machines themselves and there seems to be an issue if you run in Hyper-V environment.
I can confirm the same as I run in VMWare Workstation and encountered the same issue. This should reduce the scope of your search for a solution.

"Emulating Devices with Hyper-V
When you install Visual Studio 2015 on real hardware without virtualization, you can choose features that enable emulation of Windows and Android devices using Hyper-V. When you install into Hyper-V, you will not be able to emulate the Windows or Android devices. This is because the emulators are themselves virtual machines, and you cannot currently host a VM inside another VM. The workaround is to have real Windows or Android devices to which you can directly deploy and debug your application."

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw%28v=vs.140%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#bkmk_offline

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add any further information (such as the reference) to the original answer by editing it, instead of just putting it in the comments. Great that you provide references, by the way.

Comment: This was not on a VM, this is a on-the-metal laptop.  The only thing that is a little strange is that I have VS2013 installed, and cannot remove it, or I will have no way to keep developing.  Everything we have tried has not worked including using ISOs, downloads, and even the latest patch for Win10 that came out this week.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with VS2015, I ended up reformatting my computer because of VS2015. What I did was: I downloaded the default settings of VS2015. Then it worked ! But downloading the features is scary. It was necessary for me to have Tools and the Windows SDK and I needed Common C++. So I downloaded first the Common C++, then created a restore point (if ever the installation for the Tools and Windows SDK will be unsuccessful, I have a back-up for my files). Now VS2015 works fine, but not really sure if you can freely download some of the features. Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

it helped me to re-enable "Download updates from other PCs" which I had disabled for some reason.

to do that
1. go to Settings / Update and Security / Windows Update / Advanced options / Choose how updates are delivered 
2. ensure it is "On" and "PCs on my local network and PCs on the Internet"

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems installing VS2015 Professional after my BizSpark license for Enterprise expired. I had to do all of the above, as well as delete/rename the folder

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18
```

and disable Windows Defender. Still, my installation would flash the splash screen and hang. What finally worked was to remove .NET 2.0 and 3.5 from the Windows Components. (In addition to all the steps already listed, not instead.) I also made sure my SHA1 values for the ISO file matched and ran the TotalUninstaller tool to remove every trace of the old installation.

Now I am having a different issue, so wish me luck! I actually like Windows 10 and VS2015, but there are days...

Joey