# Installing VS 2015 on Win 10, then Fatal Eror: "The specified path is too long"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, fatal-error

I've been trying all day to install Visual Studio 2015 Community with Update 1 on my Windows 10 PC but no use :(

Machine:

- PC: Windows 10 64bit Activated + More than enough space on SSD.
- ISO file was downloaded directly from MS Server and checked, it's fine.

During the installation:

- I've mounted the ISO by PowerISO.
- Temp folder and Package Cache folder were both cleared.
- Windows Defender was disabled.
- Unchecked all special features.

And the installation stops when it comes to "Visual Studio Core Features", brings up an error message.

This is my log file: http://bit.ly/vs15log

Please help and thanks in advance :)

P/s: I've heard a lot of problems while installing VS 2015 on Windows 10 According to this thread : [Visual Studio does not install correctly on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812596/visual-studio-does-not-install-correctly-on-windows-10), seems that VS 2015 is not optimized for Windows 10 yet? I really don't want to go back to that Windows 7 again :(

Comment: **.The specified path is too long: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1** this is strange. This path is not too long.

Comment: Yeah, kind of strange :(

Comment: try to create the directory structure on your own. Maybe this works.

Comment: excuse me, what do you mean by "directory structure on your own"? I've installed VS 2015 on an empty partition, not the partition of windows 10

Comment: go to  **C:\Program Files (x86)**, create here the folder **Windows Kits** and now create the folder **8.1**. Now try to install the VS2015

Comment: Thanks mans it works now!! It turns out that there's some problems with the Windows Kits folder. When I double-click it gives an error message. Seems to be a broken symbolic link (?). 
I've deleted that folder, created my own and it works :)
Can't believe that I did not even try to open it b4 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here is my workaround:

As written in the log file:

> The specified path is too long: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1

Actually it's not "too long", it's just broken. When I double-clicked, it gave an error message (sorry I forgot it). I don't know why, maybe due to a broken symbolic link (?).

So I deleted the folder Windows Kits, then created a new folder named Windows Kits, and then another new folder named 8.1 inside.

Finally it worked!